# Spring MVC - POJO throw Еxception from invalid spring:form information how to how to catch in controller

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I created POJO which validate the product name not be less than 3 characters. In JSP use spring:form  to create object at submit. When I send a blank form 'name' POJO throw Еxception. Controller have @Modelattribute product in POST method , but product object is not created and APP crash with Exception from POJO. I want to catch this exception and added back as an error message to the user. What I do wrong.

POJO Code:

```
public class Product {
private int id;
private String name;
private Department deparment;

public Product() {
}

// Create product from DB
public Product(int id, String name, Department deparment) {
    this.id = id;
    try {
        setName(name);
        setDeparment(deparment);
    } catch (ProductException | DeparmentException e) {
        e.getMessage();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

// Create new product in DB
public Product(String name, Department deparment) {
    try {
        setName(name);
        setDeparment(deparment);
    } catch (ProductException | DeparmentException e) {
        e.getMessage();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) throws ProductException {
    if (name.length() > 3) {
        this.name = name;
    } else {
        throw new ProductException("Invalid name for product");
    }
}

public Department getDeparment() {
    return deparment;
}

public void setDeparment(Department deparment) throws DeparmentException {
    if (deparment != null) {
        this.deparment = deparment;
    } else {
        throw new DeparmentException("Invalid deparment for product");
    }

}
```

JSP Code :

```
    <c:if test="${not empty error}">
    <p style="color: red">Error: ${error}</p>
</c:if>
<c:if test="${not empty success}">
    <p style="color: green">${success}</p>
</c:if>

<springForm:form action="product" method="post" commandName="product">

    <springForm:input type="text" placeholder="Име на продукта"
        path="name" pattern=".{3,}" />
    <br>
    <br>

    <select id="department" name="department">
        <option value="0">Department</option>
        <!-- Var mi e promenlivata items e masiva-->

        <c:forEach var="department" items="${departments}">
            <option value="${department.id}">${department.name}</option>
        </c:forEach>
    </select>
    <button>Create</button>
</springForm:form>
```

Controller Code:

```
public class ProductController {

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/product")
public String showProductForm(Model viewModel) {
    DepartmentDAO deparmentDAO = new DepartmentDAO();
    List<Department> departments = new ArrayList<Department>();
    try {
        departments = deparmentDAO.selectAllDeparments();
    } catch (DeparmentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    viewModel.addAttribute("departments", departments);
    viewModel.addAttribute("product", new Product());

    return "product";
}

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/product")
public String addNewProduct(@ModelAttribute Product product, Model viewModel,@ModelAttribute("department") int departmentId, BindingResult result) {
    DepartmentDAO departmentDAO = new DepartmentDAO();
    ProductDAO productDAO = new ProductDAO();

    if (departmentId == 0) {
        viewModel.addAttribute("error", "Department is not selected.");
        return showProductForm(viewModel);
    }

    try {
        Department department = departmentDAO.getDepartmentById(departmentId);
        product.setDeparment(department);
        productDAO.addProduct(product);
    } catch (ProductException | DeparmentException e) {
        viewModel.addAttribute("error", e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
        return showProductForm(viewModel);
    }
    viewModel.addAttribute("success", "Въведохте успешно Продукта: <br>" + product.getName());

    return showProductForm(viewModel);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't throw an Exception from the setter; if you do that Spring is unable to populate the model to pass it to the controller.
You should use validation for that; either roll out a custom one, which may throw the exception you can catch:

```
public void validate (Product p) throws ProductException() {...}
```

or use standard validation support by Spring:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/product")
public String addNewProduct(@ModelAttribute @Valid Product product, BindingResult result, Model viewModel,@ModelAttribute("department") int departmentId, BindingResult result) {...
```

see spring documentation for more info; I would suggest this one, it's the standard way